# Class size change between application and exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a console application that instantiates a class (say `class X`). The class is defined in a dll -> X.dll.  When I print the size of class in the application and inside one of class's functions (which gets called when application invokes it) - I notice a size change.

I am using the VS 2010 and the application prints class size as 6304 and the function prints that as 6352. I have compiled both the exe and dll in Release|Win32 mode. Both have `WIN32` and `_WINDOWS` defined. But do not have `WIN64` defined.

What I noticed more is when I print `sizeof(time_t)` in the exe, it prints 4 and the function in dll prints 8. Think this could be a problem.

Any idea where I should check?

Comment: What problems do you think this will cause?

Comment: I'd rather be worried about the class size than anything else...

Comment: @Xeo: Why would you be worried about your class size to be something specific? Care to explain?

Comment: @Als: It just strikes me as odd to have a class that is 6KB big.

Comment: @Als: if the DLL and the application report different sizes, they cannot exchange data safely between them, because the compilers laid out the struct differently for each one. Different compiler flags are the most probable cause.

Comment: @Xeo: Ah okay,You are pointing to the class size being 6KB, I misunderstood your comment,Agreed thats an rather **BIG ASS** Class.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes : I agree. This class' size change when seen from the DLL or the EXE **does** matter.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Okay,I get it.Not my area of expertise so good to know.

Comment: @All: It causes heap corruption since the application uses new X() to allocate memory.

Comment: @Klaim: You'd like to see the definition of a class 6kB big? Also, the problem is very likely in the project settings.

Comment: I had exactly same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472616/memory-address-of-a-member-variable-of-argument-objects-changes-when-dll-functio

Comment: @Prabhu read Michael Burr's answer to get the idea about `time_t`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that it will likely be a problem if a DLL and an EXE ***disagree on the layout of data types***.

However, I cannot see any other explanation besides that you must be using ***different project settings*** between the two projects.

In order to find the culprit, ***mark both projects*** in the solution (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Left Click), then bring up the properties dialog. The dialog will now only display the ***properties that are the same*** for both projects in the selected configuration. Despite the dialog at a first glance seeming to be a modal one, you can click on one of the projects to see only its properties, and you can also again mark both of them, so you can ***switch back and forth between those views***. So far, I have usually found the problem using this technique.

If this fails, you can always ***compare the project files***. They being quite chatty XML files makes this harder, though.

Comment: You can also see the full compiler command line arguments (I know it's there in the project settings somewhere) and compare them.

Comment: Or look in the log files created by the build.

Comment: That is correct!! Had to force include one header file for all project which sets the layout of data types.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)?

I already had to deal with such different sizes of the same class.

This leads at best to crashes (as your code will try to read/write beyond the actual data of the class), and at worst to strange bugs (like setting the value of a member variable to 42 and, when then reading it to see the value is instead 1376256 or something like that).

The cause was usually tied to alignment problems.

here's what you can do to see if your problem is an alignment problem:

Right before (or after) your class definition, add the following line:

```
#pragma pack(show)
```

In the compilation output, you should see something like:

1>.\test_align.cpp(59) : warning C4810: value of pragma pack(show) == 8

This will show the alignment when your header is compiled. This will appear each time the header is included in a CPP file. This value should **always** be the same, both in the DLL compilation and the EXE compilation.

If they are different, even once, then you have a mis-alignment problem...

### Default Struct Alignement for the project?

Perhaps your DLL has its default struct alignment set to 1, while the EXE has another value.
Please, check in the both the project's properties:
Section "C/C++", Sub-section "Code Generation", property "Struct Member Alignment".

For everything to work correctly, both projects should have the same values.

If the EXE and the DLL have different values, then you must correct that (the "default" value is usually the good one: Select "inherit from parent or project value").

### Pragma pack?

There is another way to break the alignment, that is, through the use of `#pragma pack` statements. For example:

```
#pragma pack(show) // this will show the default value, i.e. 8 on my project

struct Data8       // the sizeof this struct is 8 bytes
{
   bool     m_bValue ;
   int      m_iValue ;
} ;

#pragma pack(push, 1)

#pragma pack(show) // this will show the now current value, i.e. 1

struct Data1       // the sizeof this struct is 5 bytes, thanks to the packing
{
   bool     m_bValue ;
   int      m_iValue ;
} ;

#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(show) // this will show again the default value, i.e. 8
```

So, search for `#pragma pack` statements, and verify they are always correctly set and unset (if you have a push without a pop, then you probably have an error).

### The class has the same alignment on both project?

If you don't find the problem in your class, perhaps the problem is instead in one of the class/struct it inherits from or it has as member variable.

So verify them, the same way you verified the main class.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2010, the `time_t` type should be a 64-bit value (whether the build target is 32-bit or 64-bit).  This can be overridden for 32-bit target builds by defining `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` - so you should make sure that isn't being defined in your application build (or if it needs to be defined there, you'll need to also define it for your DLL or use the `__time32_t` type in the DLL class definition).

I'd also make sure that you don't have different packing options set for the DLL and the application builds (note that the packing configuration can be changed in poorly written header files). Look for the `/Zp` compiler option in build logs and/or the `#pragma pack` lines in header files without a corresponding `#pragma pack()` that resets to the default setting.