# memory address of a member variable of argument objects changes when dll function is called

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

class SomeClass 
    {
        //some members
        MemberClass one_of_the_mem_; 
    }

I have a function `foo( SomeClass *object )` within a dll, it is being called from an exe.

**Problem**

address of `one_of_the_mem_` changes during the time the dll call is dispatched.

**Details**:

**before** the call is made (from exe):

```
             '&(this).one_of_the_mem_' - `0x00e913d0`
```

**after** - in the dll itself :

```
             '&(this).one_of_the_mem_' - `0x00e913dc`
```

The address of object remains constant. It is only the member whose address shift by **c** every time.

I want some pointers regarding how can I troubleshoot this problem.

**Code :**

Code from Exe

> stat = module->init ( this, 
>                                   object_a, 
>                                              &object_b, 
>                                              object_c,
>   con_dir
>                                            );

Code in DLL

```
Status_C ModuleClass( SomeClass *object, int index, Config *conf, const char* name)
{
    _ASSERT(0); //DEBUGGING HOOK
    ...
```

**Update 1:**

I compared the Offsets of members following Michael's instruction and they are the same in both cases.

**Update 2:**

I found a way to dump the class layout and noticed the difference in size, I have to figure out why is that happening though.

linked is the question that I found to dump class layout.

**Update 3:**
[image: Class layout difference between exe and dll, but don't know why yet]
**Final Update** : Solved the problem, much thanks to Michael Burr.

it turned out that one of the build was using 32 bit time, `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` was defined in it and the other one was using 64 bit time. So it generated the different layout for the object, attached is the difference file.

[image: Diff in two classes due to sizeof `time_t']

Comment: Is it possible that the DLL was compiled with a different version of the class?

Comment: Can you post a minimal, complete piece of code please that reproduces this?

Comment: Sounds like maybe your exe and dll use different compiler (alignment) flags.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I don't know if this is enough or not, I can not provide the actual code due to restrictions. sorry.

Comment: Nasgul, you don't have to post your actual code, but you do need to post code that demonstrates the problem you describe. If you can't post your real code, then write some new code that exhibits the same problem. Start by showing the relationship between `module->init` and `ModuleClass` functions. It would help if your functions had the same number of parameters.

Comment: If you post the actual class definition (strip out the member functions if you're concerned about proprietary stuff - they likely have little influence on the class layout) we might be able to point you toward a possible culprit. Maybe.  Even better, dump the `offsetof()` values of each member to the console or other log, and that should help you zero in on the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I checked the offset and they are exactly same in both the places. I can post the output if you want.

Comment: @Nasgul: I don't see how if the object address is the same and the offsets are the same that the address of the member can be different, unless you're performing some incorrect cast that you haven't mentioned yet (is multiple inheritance in the picture at all?). Also, you might notice something if you step through the call a the assembly level.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Let me try to put the difference the compiler shows. it shows me the discrepancy of `40 bytes` but at runtime `offsetof` does print the same offset.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I just uploaded the image of diff between two class layout (exe's and dll's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DLL was probably compiled with different set of compiler options (or maybe even a slightly different header file) and the class layout is different as a result.

For example, if one was built using debug flags and other wasn't or even if different compiler versions were used. For example, the libraries used by different compiler versions might have subtle differences and if your class incorporates a type defined by the library you could have different layouts.

As a concrete example, with Microsoft's compiler iterators and containers are sensitive to release/debug, _SECURE_SCL on/off , and _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING on/off setting (at least up though VS 2008 - VS 2010 may have changed some of this to a certain extent).  See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/352699/secure-scl-is-broken-in-release-builds for some details.

These kinds of issues make using C++ classes across DLL boundaries a bit more fragile than using straight C interfaces.  They can occur in C structures as well, but it seems like C++ libraries have these differences more often (I think that's the nature of having richer functionality).

Another layout-changing issue that occurs every now and then is having a different structure packing option in effect in the different compiles. One thing that can 'hide' this is that pragmas are often used in headers to set structure packing to a certain value, and sometimes you may come across a header that does this without changing it back to the default (or more correctly the previous setting). If you have such a header, it's easy to have it included in the build for one module, but not another.

Comment: @Nasgul: OK, so that diff in the recent update confirms that the `class VM_Platform` layout is different between the two modules.  I think you'll need to look closely at the difference(s) in compiler version/options between the builds.  Looking closely at the definition of `VM_Platform` and `VM_SourceRegistry` might give a clue, too.  A small program that just outputs `sizeof(VM_Platform)` and/or `sizeof(VM_SourceRegistry)` might make it easy to try different options to see what effect they have.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I figured that there was a difference in size of the VM_SourceRegistry because one of them had a `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` macro, so other was using 64 bit time and hence the incompatible. I am sorry if I wasted too much of your time but I learnt really good things while solving this, so no regrets. Thanks a lot again. posting the difference

Comment: I still have one doubt though - why is the `vfptr` size different? in one it has 32bit other has 64bit

Comment: @Nasgul: the `vfptr` is likely not really a different size; the compiler is probably just arranging things to ensure that the embedded `time_t` value will be 64-bit aligned.

Answer (score 0):

that sounds a bit wierd, you should show more code, it should 'move' if it being passed by ref, it sounds more like a copy of it is being made and that having the member function called.

Perhaps the DLL versions is compiled against a different version that you are referencing. check and make sure the header file is for the same version as the dll.

Recompile the library if you can.